# Github Desktop sign in different account (acc 2nd), still old account(acc 1st) repositories are visible

Tags: github, github-desktop

I was using another github account (abc@gmail.com), but now I wanted to use xyz@gmail.com account, and signout signin still keeps the repositories of abc@gmail.com Yes I am using Github Desktop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the desktop app uses your default browsers cache to get the sign in information. I would recommend clearing your cache and cookies then closing all browser instances once that's done. (Make sure time range says all time if in chrome or edge) Make sure to be already signed out of the desktop app before doing this to avoid any cross caching.